# Should I encrypt the signature?

Tags: security, language-agnostic, encryption, cryptography, digital-signature

I know, according to [this article](http://world.std.com/~dtd/sign_encrypt/sign_encrypt7.html) that I should Sign the message, then Encrypt the message.

My program operates like so:

- Get the bytes of the message
- Digitally sign the message, and store the signature in a separate byte array
- Encrypt the message
- Send the signature, then the encrypted message in a packet

Should I do it like so?

- Get the bytes of the message
- Digitally sign the message, and concatenate it with the bytes of the message
- Encrypt the array containing the message and signature
- Send the encrypted data

Appreciate the assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Digitally sign the message, and concatenate it with the bytes of the message.

You need to know where one ends and the other starts, but sure.  Some APIs just take a key and a message and produce an output of bytes, and then instead of having a separate verify (data)->boolean step, they take a single bunch of bytes and either return the verified message or fail.

So yes, you can send

```
encrypt(
    concat(
        sign(message, signerPrivateKey), message),
        encryptionKey)
```

To get a verified message, the receiver has to have received two keys ahead of time: the signers public key and the decrypt key which is the same as the encryptionKey for symmetric crypto and which must be a guarded secret.

If you want to use asymmetric crypto so you only need to exchange public keys, and your message is not always shorter than a key, typically you generate a one-time use symmetric key and only encrypt that asymmetrically since asymmetric algos are typically more expensive than symmetric ones.

```
oneTimeUseSymmetricCryptoKey := generateKey()
concat(
    encryptAssymetric(
        oneTimeUseSymmetricCryptoKey,
        encrypterPrivateKey),
    encryptSymmetric(
        concat(sign(message, signerPrivateKey), message),
        oneTimeUseSymmetricCryptoKey))
```

None of this though prevents the message forwarding attack described in the link above.  To do that, you need to authenticate the sender, e.g. by choosing a public key to verify the signature *AND* a key to decrypt based on a sender address which is arrived at independently from the exchange of encrypted bytes.

Comment: I will take this into advice.  I will be using asymmetric encryption, regardless of the cost.  My plan will be the following:
- Concatenate the sender and recipient's ID with the message
- Digitally sign the entire message (with sender/recipient's ID)
- Concatenate the signature and message, and encrypt it

Comment: Is there any specific reason that makes you want to use asymmetric encryption for the whole message? Generally speaking, it doesn't make your scheme more robust and may be infeasible for large messages.

Comment: It could be faulty logic, but I was wanting the entire conversation to be digitally signed.  Figure, I might as well use asymmetric encryption as well.  large messages will be uncommon.

Comment: Encrypting a whole message using asymmetric algorithms is something I would generally frown upon. You can sign all the messages regardless of the encryption algorithm you use. My advice is to avoid rolling out your own encryption protocol and stick to well known standards. Take a look at http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2009-06-11-cryptographic-right-answers.html

Comment: This would deserve an answer on its own. In short: AES has no input limit (whereas RSA ciphertext size is equal to the key's modulus size, that is usually 1024 to 4096 bit long), it is easier to avoid chosen plaintext attacks, chosen ciphertext attacks. Bottom line: cryptography is hard, not sticking with standards will get you in troubles.

Comment: @Mike, regarding using asymmetric crypto for the whole thing, if you do have a small hard upper-bound on the message size, then I think you're fine.  But if large messages might happen (even after code maintenance), I'd still opt with the two-crypt solution.  If you have the asymmetrically encrypted secret outside the signature, and you are doing authentication based on looking up public keys based on sender ID, then you lose nothing since the only one who can impersonate the sender and encrypt their own symmetric key is one who already knows at least one of the two private keys.

Comment: Alright, I'm convinced.  I'll use Diffie-Hellman to get the symmetric key.  @Mike Samuel and Giuseppe: Nice explanations